# T Format date inside json

Tags: jquery, django

I am getting json from backend like this :

```
 {
   "datas":[
      {
         "id":4,
         "create_date":"2021-03-18T21:11:57.239Z"
      },
      {
         "id":5,
         "create_date":"2021-03-19T19:37:05.829Z"
      }
   ]
}
```

and looping through json like below :

```
 $(data.datas).each(function(index,value){
        html += `<tr><th scope="row">${index+1}</th>
              <td>${value.id}</td>
              <td>${value.create_date}</td>
              <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-dark">View Car</a></td>
            </tr>`
 })
```

But, here `create_date` is just printing in td column like this `2021-03-18T21:11:57.239Z` . So, how can i make this display like this `2021-03-18 & 21:11 am/pm` in each tds ?

**My attempt** :

```
var created_date = value.create_date;
console.log(created_date.split("T")[0]);//2021-03-18
console.log(created_date.split("T")[1])//21:11:57.239Z (how can i remove 57.239Z..)
```

I am open for both solution i.e : backend as well as frontend . For my backend i am using django let me know if you need to see any code from backend .

Comment: try like this `<td>${value.create_date|date:"M d, Y" }}</td>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply **[MomentJS](https://momentjs.com/)** to format the date time in **front-end**.

Pre-requisites:

- Add the `MomentJS` script into your `HTML`

```js
// Demo with assign sample data into createdDate
var created_date = new Date();
console.log(moment(created_date).format("YYYY-MM-DD & HH:mm a"));
// Result: 2021-04-02 & 15:16 pm
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Reference: [MomentJS Parse string format](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/)

Answer (score 1):

For solving it from backend side. You can set it in **settings.py**

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DATETIME_FORMAT': "%Y-%m-%d & %H:%M %p",
}
```

More information in [DRF Documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/settings/#date-and-time-formatting)

The output will looks like it:

**"create_date": "2021-03-18 & 21:11 AM"**

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer but , data are coming from db . so is there any way to make that work ?

Comment: try @Vel's suggestion, ${value.create_date|date:"M d, Y" }}

Comment: in jquery code it will not work i guess because i am generating trs using jquery/ajax code .